# getUserMedia not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, video, webcam

I'm trying to setup video streaming site. I found, that you can use webcam from browser with help of getUserMedia. 
Here is my javascript code, that I wrote:

```
function stream() {
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||     navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, load, error);
    }
}

function load(source) {
    document.getElementById("video").src = window.URL.createObjectURL(source);
    alert("Connected");
}

function error(e) {
    alert("Error:") + e;
}
```

Here I have my HTML tag:

```
<video id="video" autoplay></video>
```

My problem is, that when I open my site and allow browser to use webcam and microphone, I can hear myself, but video isn't loaded. Video frame resizes to 2px x 2px black square. Where am I doing mistakes?

Answer (score 3):

While I can't reproduce your issue on either Chrome or Firefox, I believe your issue is with the attempt to use `autoplay`. The recommended way to display a webcam stream is to add a listener for `loadedmetadata` and explicitly call `play`. My suspicion is that your browser is attempting to play the stream before it knows the width and height, leading to an invalid state.

MDN snippet: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia)

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
   navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } },
      function(stream) {
         var video = document.querySelector('video');
         video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
         video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
           video.play();
         };
      },
      function(err) {
         console.log("The following error occured: " + err.name);
      }
   );
} else {
   console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
}
```

The key part for you is:

```
video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
  video.play();
};
```

Also, I don't believe that `msGetUserMedia` or `oGetUserMedia` exist. You should avoid adding browser prefixes without verifying that they exist (since they may exist somewhere with a different API).

---

And of course, it's always worth checking that you actually have a webcam and it is connected! (e.g. can you use it from another application? how about from another website?)

Comment: I changed my code according to your suggestion, but it didn't help. Also, in Camera application in Windows 8 my webcam is working just fine. And I looked at other sites about getUserMedia and demos on them didn't work either. And I tried it on my mobile phone (Google Chrome browser) and it works there. Maybe problem with my PC?

Comment: If you're running the latest version of Chrome (42), you could try reporting it to the developers: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list (they may ask you to run some diagnostics)

Comment: Okey, but it's not working even in firefox. But in Firefox some error occurs, don't know which error it is.

Comment: Okey, I just woke up and tried it on my brothers computer. It's working there, so where could be problem?

Comment: @LinhyCZ  , did you ever figure out what the solution was?
I'm noticing your problem, but I only get it on a mac.  Did you ever determine a resolution?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access your ../*.html file directly. Chrome won't correctly for a number of features due to the Same Origin Policy. There are two solutions.

Set up a simple http server. You can do this by enabling apache to serve your local files for you.

Disable same origin policy for chrome.

A quick google for both will turn up several full detailed examples on how to do either. I would suggest option 1 because this will emulate how your webpage will behave when it is live.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the stream directly to the video tag. There is no need to create an object URL. My solution is an edit to the @Dave's solution.

```
 video.srcObject = stream;
```

instead of this

```
 video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
```